# Windows Server Essentials Experience DirSync Not Working After Adding Second Domain Controller

Tags: domain-controller, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-essentials

I recently did a domain upgrade for our office to Windows Server 2012 r2. Upon seeing the new Windows Server Essentials Experience and its ability to perform a directory sync with Office 365, I installed the optional server components to enable this feature and everything was working fine. Upon adding a secondary domain controller to the domain, I started getting the following error:

> Action needed for Microsoft Azure Active Directory password
>   synchronization
>
> Occurrences SERVER 1/6/2015 3:58 PM Details The current configuration
>   of Microsoft Azure Active Directory password synchronization does not
>   support multiple domain controllers. A configuration update is needed
>   to support multiple domain controllers.
>
> Resolution Open Windows Powershell with administrative privilege, and
>   run the cmdlet Update-WssMsoPasswordSynchronzation.

Upon opening PowerShell (as admin) to run the above command, I find that the commandlet does not exist. Looking more into it I managed to find only a single post of someone else with the same problem but no real solution...

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ca7c404e-8378-4155-8273-4e00e1a47d0e/azure-password-synchronization-does-not-support-multiple-domain-controllers?forum=WindowsAzureAD&prof=required

Its like the directory sync through the Windows Server Essentials Experience is a version of DirSync but with far less control than the full version. I am not sure how to fix the problem if I cannot run full DirSync commands.

Both domain controllers are running Windows Server 2012 r2 Standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been a known issue for the Windows Server Essentials product line.

There is a bug fix for the issue.

[KB Article Describing the issue with a link to the rollup package](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2974308)

[Server Essentials Blog Acknowledging the issue](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sbs/archive/2013/10/28/enabling-multiple-instances-of-windows-server-essentials-experience-in-your-environment.aspx)

Comment: Glad it applied.  Best of luck to you.